# Can I combine Smarty tpl and HTML highlighting, hinting, snippets, autocomplete in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, smarty3

Using VS Code, I have "Smarty syntax highlighting" installed, works fine.  I also set `"emmet.includeLanguages": { "smarty": "html" },`
so I can use emmet abbreviations, but I do not get the hinting/autocomplete for HTML.

I can add `"files.associations": { "*.tpl":"html" }` but then I loose the Smarty syntax highlighting.

Is there any way to treat the file as an HTML, and thus get the "stock" HTML emmet, autocomplete, hinting, and formatting but use the Smarty syntax highlighting offered by the extension? (or does anyone know of an extension that does this all-in-one?)

Answer (score 2):

I used it that way and it worked.

```
emmet.includeLanguages": {
   "smarty": "html"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try ...

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "tpl": "html"
},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "smarty": "html"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I needed to use Smarty in the .html files. I made it my settings.json file and it helped me:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.html": "smarty"
},

"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "smarty": "html"
}
```